# Selecting set number of points within polygon grid cells using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, select-by-location, vector-grid

I have a polygon grid with 1 square kilometer area cells, and over it a set of points, like so:

[image: points over grid]

What i need to do is select and extract only a single random point per grid cell.

I could do that manually and it wouldn't take too much time as the area i have to cover is not that big, but is there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using function from processing toolbox:

1. Take grid cell and join its id (or other unique) attribute to related points - Use **Join attributes by location** and join unique attribute (i.e. "id_grid") from grid layer to point layer. This create new point layer with new attribute - "id_grid" of corresponding grid.
2. Select only one point per gird - Use **Random selection within subsets**. As input choose your new layer from step one, for *ID Field* select "id_grid" and set number required points to be selected (in your case 1)
3. Extracting to new point layer - Right click on layer, select **Save As...**, set output parametres (format, CRS...) and check *Save only selected features*

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create an R Script GUI widget, which will run just like any other tool in the processing toolbox. The script below will allow you to select from you layers a polygon and a point data set, and will return a randomly sampled set of points wherein no more than one point will remain in within each individual polygon:

```
##polygons=vector
##points=vector
##output=output vector
library(sp)

samp <- lapply(1:nrow(polygons),function(i){
  x <- points[polygons[i,],]
  if (nrow(x) == 0){
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    sub <- sample(1:nrow(x), size = 1)
    return(x[sub,])
  }
})

output = Reduce(rbind,samp[unlist(lapply(samp,function(i) class(i) != "NULL"))])
```

Note that if this is your first time running an R Script in QGIS, the first time you run it may take several minutes because it has to install the libraries. Each time after that will be significantly faster.